# Remove image outputs from TensorBoard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

My TensorBoard log files grow huge because – it seems – every image summary ever generated is stored. This even though in TensorBoard, it seems like I can only look at the most recent image. And I only need the most recent image anyway.

Is there a way to let TensorBoard know that I only need the latest iamge? I looked at the `SummaryWriter` API docs but there is no obvious flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I work on TensorBoard. To the best of my knowledge, the logs are append only. However when TensorBoard loads them into memory, it uses reservoir sampling so they don't consume all your memory. In the future, we may be implementing a system that will reservoir sampling during the writing phase, or possibly, a tool for compressing logs so they only contain what TensorBoard needs.

While TensorBoard image dashboard only shows the most recent image at the moment, we'd be hesitant to write tools to remove the previous ones, since we may be extending the dashboard to show more than the most recent sample.

Comment: Is there some way of doing a partitioned chunk or something so that we can use images for live monitoring and just delete the last chunk when we've moved on?